# Relationship between 2 tables with a relationship table

Tags: sql, laravel, relationship

I have 3 tables like the following diagram:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WENmI.png

I created a relationship table between users and organizations

I would like to retrieve a collection with the list of organizations for each user.

Currently I am getting a collection in which a user comes back several times.

```
Collection {#226 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => {#232 ▼
      +"name": "GotExx"
      +"avatar_path": "gotexx.jpg"
      +"orga-name": "My orga 1"
      +"slug": "my-orga-1"
      +"orga-avatar": "myorga1_logo.png"
    }
    1 => {#228 ▼
      +"name": "GotExx"
      +"avatar_path": "gotexx.jpg"
      +"orga-name": "My orga 2"
      +"slug": "my-orga-2"
      +"orga-avatar": "myorga2_logo.png"
    }
    2 => {#234 ▼
      +"name": "GotExx"
      +"avatar_path": "gotexx.jpg"
      +"orga-name": "My orga 3"
      +"slug": "my-orga-3"
      +"orga-avatar": "myorga3_logo.png"
    }
    3 => {#233 ▼
      +"name": "root"
      +"avatar_path": null
      +"orga-name": "My orga 2"
      +"slug": "my-orga-2"
      +"orga-avatar": "myorga2_logo.png"
    }
  ]
}
```

```sql
select users.name, users.avatar_path, organizations.name, organizations.slug, organizations.avatar_path 
from relation_organization
right join users on relation_organization.user_id = users.id
left join organizations on relation_organization.organization_id = organizations.id
```

ideally I would like to get this:

```
Collection {#226 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#232 ▼
      +"name": "GotExx"
      +"avatar_path": "gotexx.jpg" 
      +"organizations" => {
        0 => {
          +"orga-name": "My orga 1"
          +"slug": "my-orga-1"
          +"orga-avatar": "myorga1_logo.png"
        }
        1 => {
          +"orga-name": "My orga 2"
          +"slug": "my-orga-2"
          +"orga-avatar": "myorga2_logo.png"
        }
        2 => {
          +"orga-name": "My orga 3"
          +"slug": "my-orga-3"
          +"orga-avatar": "myorga3_logo.png"
        }
      }
    }
    1 => {#232 ▼
      +"name": "root"
      +"avatar_path": "null" 
      +"organizations" => {
        0 => {
          +"orga-name": "My orga 2"
          +"slug": "my-orga-2"
          +"orga-avatar": "myorga2_logo.png"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel preferred way.

1. Create models.
2. Define relationships.
3. Use eager loading when retrieving data.

Creating models and relationships.

**User model**

```php
public class User extends Model
{
    public function organizations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Organization::class);
    }
}
```

**Organization model**

```php
public class Organization extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

Using eager loading when fetching.

**Controller function**

```php
$usersWithOrganizations = User::with('organizations')->get();
```

Comment: Great it works perfectly, I guess I can chain constraints? Let's say I want to recover users from an organization, I would just have to do something like `$organizationWithUsers = Organization::with('users')->where('organization_id', $organization->id)->get();` ?

Comment: Yes you can add constrains to the `organizations` table like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is where Laravel really shines with relationships.  Pull your `users` with an eager load with `organizations` all in one query.  e.g.

```
$users = User::with('organizations')->get().
```

Your `$users` will now have all users in the system, with their attached organizations, listed one time per user, as your question asks for.

If you want to limit the fields drawn as you had in your **SQL**, you can use select:

```
$users = User::select('avatar_path', 'name')->with(['organizations' => function($query){
      $query->select('name', 'slug', 'avatar_path );
}])->get().
```

This all assumes you have the `organizations` relationship set up correctly on your **Users** model.